# vscode on wsl2: Run and Debug error: Starting directory does not exist

Tags: debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I want to program an STM32 board. My compiled C++ code is called `firmwar.elf`.

The development board has an stlink built in. So this is my prefered debugger.

I am using a WSL2 system to run Ubuntu. I can successfully launch into this subsystem with vscode. I followed [this guide by microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl). I also installed a custom Linux-Kernel to attach the USB-Device to WSL2. All of that works.

However, I can't get the debugger to launch.

In vscode I click on the `Run and Debug` menu. Then I select my profile and press play.
This returns the following:

```
 *  Executing task: make bin 
 *  The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) "/app" does not exist.
```

My `launch.json` file contains this part:

```
[...]    
{
  "name": "ST-Link: Debug Application",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
  "executable": "./firmware.elf",
  "servertype": "stutil",
  "request": "launch",
  "type": "cortex-debug",
  "device": "STM32L432KC",
  "runToEntryPoint": "main",
  "interface": "swd",
  "preLaunchTask": "build_debug"
},
[...]
```

And yes, the `/app` directory exists and this is the place `firmware.elf` is saved.

This is my file structure:

```
v workspaceFolder
  > .vscode
  v app
    > inc
    > src
    firmware.bin
    firmware.elf
    firmware.map
    Makefile
  > library
  .gitignore
  .gitmodules
```

vscode is probably searching somewhere else for the path `${workspaceFolder}/app` which explains the error.

What can I do to fix this?